# How to get jquery element-object parent from id variable

Tags: jquery, html

I'm missing something basic here (newish to JQuery).
I have the id of an element ex an array and wish to get it's parent.
but the parent object looks like a whole function declaration of some type, when I display it.
What am  I missing please.
Thx

```
$.each(arr, function (){
    var thisElId = arr[i][0];
    alert(thisElId);  //correct
    var EnclSpanParentText = $('#' + thisElId).parents(".accordion-heading").text;
    alert("SpanParent " + EnclSpanParentText);
    if (EnclSpanParentText == "Read")
```

[image: markup image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You're using *`parents`*, which gives you the full ancestry of the element, not just its parent. It's not clear to me whether you meant to do that. If you're looking for its closest parent matching the given selector, use `closest(...)` or `parents(...).first()`
2. You're not *calling `text`, you're just referring to it. To *call* it (since it's a function), you add `()` to the end.

So either

```
var EnclSpanParentText = $('#' + thisElId).parents(".accordion-heading").text();
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------^^
alert("SpanParent " + EnclSpanParentText);
```

or

```
var EnclSpanParentText = $('#' + thisElId).closest(".accordion-heading").text();
// ----------------------------------------^^^^^^^---------------------------^^
alert("SpanParent " + EnclSpanParentText);
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

first of all text() is a function not a property 
second you can use this .. as per my understanding.

```
 $.each(arr, function (i,o)
    {
        var thisElId = $(this);
          alert(thisElId);  //correct
          var EnclSpanParentText =thisElId.parent().text() ;
          alert("SpanParent " + EnclSpanParentText);

        if (EnclSpanParentText == "Read")
```

Comment: Thank You gents. Much appreciated. the function brackets and Parents worked..., but Parent did not,..may be because it has 2 parent spans..the outer has the text values I want  (Read,Update,Create,Delete)

Comment: you can select which parent you want